# C++ Iterator declare from typedef std::map as template argument

Tags: c++

How can I declare an iterator for template argument map?

I know I could pass it as argument from main function as another template argument, but if I don't, how can I declare it?

```
template< typename container >
int print_data( container map )
{
    map::iterator iter; // this is wrong
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::map< int, double > Map;
    Map new_map;

    print_data< Map >( new_map );
}
```

Comment: `typename container::iterator` or use automatic type deducation `auto iter{map.begin()};`

Answer (score 2):

While

```
map::iterator iter; // this is wrong
```

is true. That's only because you use the scope resolution operator on an object, instead of something that designates a scope, like a class name or a namespace. So this:

```
typename container::iterator iter;
```

Would be correct. Note the `typename` keyword is important and mandatory. You must let the compiler know this dependent name you are accessing is a type, so the line would be parsed as a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use a C++11 (or later) compiler, you have couple of more ways to declare `iter`.

1. If you can declare and initialize it in one statement, you can use:

   ```
   auto iter = map.begin();
   ```
2. You can also use `decltype` to deduce the type.

   ```
   using iterator_type = decltype(map.begin());
   iterator_type iter;
   ```

I would recommend using the first method. It is less code to deal with. It's also a better programming habit to declare and initialize a variable in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
typename Container::iterator iter = ...;
```

The compiler defaults to seeing template members as variables, if it's a type you have to say so with "typename".